# Compound class selector in RobotFramework with selenium

Tags: css, selenium, robotframework

Trying to check the on screen state of an element which changes from :

```
class="slide-out-div contrastBoxDark closed"
```

to

```
class="slide-out-div contrastBoxDark"
```

however using

```
Page Should Contain Element    class:slide-out-div.contrastBoxDark
```

returns

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
```

if the compound class name isn't permitted, what is a suitable locator and attribute here? Tried this, but it doesn't locate:

```
css:slide-out-div.contrastBoxDark
```

Comment: have you tried using `class:slide-out-div`? If that locates the element, then you can get the value of the `class` attribute and compare it to the expected.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing .(dot) before the class `slide-out-div` in css selector. please try the following,

```
css:.slide-out-div.contrastBoxDark
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use more than 1 class name with search by `class`. In case you want to find element by more than 1 class name, try CSS selector:

For "opened"

```
css:[class="slide-out-div contrastBoxDark"]
css:.slide-out-div.contrastBoxDark:not(.closed)
```

For "closed"

```
css:[class="slide-out-div contrastBoxDark closed"]
```

Note that `css:.slide-out-div.contrastBoxDark` will match both "closed" and "opened" elements...

Also note that your CSS selector `css:slide-out-div.contrastBoxDark` will not work as it intend to match something like `<slide-out-div class="contrastBoxDark">...</slide-out-div>` as you forgot the dot before the first class name